# Is there a way to change emoji colors on MacOS?

Tags: macos, color, emoji

So let's say I want to type emojis in a different color then yellow on MacOS. Is there any way to do it?

Just for clarification, I'm using the `Press Fn key to Show Emoji & Symbols` in the keyboard options since I think it's the most convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click and hold the emoji to choose a different emoji colour.

[image]

[List of emojis that support skin tones on Emojipedia.](https://emojipedia.org/light-skin-tone/)

Comment: This does not work for me :/ 